# docker-compose: Error: Failed to remove image for foobar: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("No such image: foobar")

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am at my wit's end as far as getting docker-compose to blitz everything. I want to have this option so that when docker gets in a weird state, as it often does, I can start over fresh.
I started with:

```
docker-compose down --rmi all -v --remove-orphans
```

Which gave me a series of errors like this:
*Failed to remove image for service foobar: 409 Client Error: Conflict ("conflict: unable to remove repository reference "foobar" (must force) - container 180399b69813 is using its referenced image 273374b463b8")*

I did the (wrong) thing in response and removed the offending images:

```
docker rmi foobar -f
```

then attempted to run my docker-compose down command again, and now I am stuck with:
*ERROR: Failed to remove image for service foobar: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("No such image: foobar:latest")*

I've tried every combo of docker and docker-compose "kill all the things" I can think of/google, and nothing seems to allow me to move past this error. Anyone know a foolproof way to blitz every part of a docker-compose configuration?

Comment: Have you tried `docker-compose up --force-recreate` to solve your issue ?

Comment: That might work to recreate containers in a decent state, but I'm looking for a dependable series of steps I could automate to remove all traces of a docker-compose setup. I find it strange that docker-compose down can put itself in a blocked state and there is no force remove everything, ignore errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of this, but I think there is a bug with the --rmi flag for docker-compose down. I think image removal happens before container removal, so the image isn't there by the time the the container and its image deletion happens. I can use down successfully if I don't use this flag, then delete images separately. If you're really stuck, @fly2matrix's idea of using --force-recreate puts things in a decent state, so you can at least try removing everything in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this worked for me :

1 - First stop the container :
`sudo docker stop <container_id>`

2 - Remove the container:
`sudo docker rm <container_id`

3 - Execute docker-compose down again:
`docker-compose down --rmi all`